# Why is this question neither closed nor on hold?

Tags: discussion, questions, quality-evaluation

We had some discussion about quality question and closing question that are not well researched and are not clear or too broad. I found the following recent question which got -2 votes and I am not sure what the OP is asking. What it is not closed?

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8849/who-is-the-person-introduced-the-islamic-legal-source-in-which-hijri-year

Can a moderator explain what the OP is asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: It wasn't closed because nobody cast close votes on it.

If you want a question closed, you need to at least vote to close it (or, if you lack sufficient reputation to cast a close vote, flag it for closure).

It's closed now.

Comment: So the moderators close questions only if they have close votes?

Comment: Moderators shouldn't even have to close questions except in exceptional situations; close votes should close questions.

Comment: That does not answer my question. I have seen question closed by moderators only. Having 2k points I can see close votes.  Do moderators close questions directly just because they are bad questions?

Comment: That is an entirely different question, which should be asked separately.